# Which Git server provide per branch authorization on windows?

Tags: windows, open-source, git

**Our requirements:**

We need a git server that have the following characteristics:

- Provides per branch authorization, i.e. two users are working on the same project, but one can access branch X only and another can access only branch Y, not vice versa
- Can be installed on windows (server)
- Preferably written either in Java, Python, PHP or C#
- Preferably has a web GUI
- Open source

We are currently using **Gitblit**, but it does not provide per branch authorization

We have a linux equivalent, that is **Gitolite**.